# Capitalize the beginning of each sentence

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to capitalize the beginning of each sentence. I have the following code from other question:

```
function applySentenceCase(str) {
    return str.replace(/.+?[\.\?\!](\s|$)/g, function (txt) {
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    });
}
```

But if i don't put a dot for a last sentence, it doesn't work properly.
For example: for string "THIS IS THE FIRST QUESTION. SECOND QUESTION" it returns "This is the first question. SECOND QUESTION"

Comment: is a sentence always ending with dot?

Comment: Do you need this for web? (js+css solutions works?)

Comment: Sidenote: Escaping such characters as `.` or `?` inside character class (`[]`) is unnecessary since they don't have special meaning there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with the regex is the grouping `(...)`

```
str.replace(/.+?(?:[.?!]\s|$)/g, function (txt) {
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    });
// Outputs
//"This is the first question. Second question. Third question
```

---

Or in es6:

```
str.replace(/.+?(?:[.?!]\s|$)/g, txt => `${txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${txt.substring(1).toLowerCase()}`);
```

**Changes**

- `[.?!]` This is a character class. There is no need to escape characters in a class.
- `(?:[.?!]\s|$)` This matches `.` or `?` or `!` followed by a space(`\s`) OR an end of string `$`

---

**What is wrong with `.+?[\.\?\!](\s|$)`**

- `[\.\?\!](\s|$)` This one tries to match a `.` or `?` or `!` always which is followed by a space or end of sentence. But clearly the last part didn't have one

Comment: This captialises every single word, which is not what the poster asks for.

Comment: @Archer Sorry my bad. Hope it is fine now

Comment: Yeah, much better now - thanks.  Have an appropriate +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't actually see the need to use regex in this case:

```
var sentences = "THIS IS THE FIRST QUESTION. SECOND QUESTION";
sentences.split('.').map(function(item) {
    var sentence = item.trim();
    return sentence.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + sentence.substr(1).toLowerCase();
}).join('. ');
```

Comment: Your code only uses dot (`.`) as separator while the original code uses `?` and `!` as well

Answer (score -1):

Match against `/^.|\.\s*\w/`.

The first part says uppercase the first character on the line.

The second part says find a `.`(end of previous sentence), any amount of white space (\s) followed by 1 alphanumeric character.

Then just replace all of it with an uppercase version.

```js
var str = "this is the first question. second question.";

console.log(str.toLowerCase().replace(/^.|\.\s*\w/ig, function(txt) {
  return txt.toUpperCase()
}));
```

**EDIT 1**

If you get it in all uppercase, simply call `toLowerCase()` on the string before replacing.

Comment: Try this with `var str = "THIS IS THE FIRST.  THIS IS THE SECOND";` - it doesn't work.